# How to handle network errors in Retrofit 2 with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2 with RxJava. So my call looks something like

```
subscriptions.add(authenticateUser(mReq, refreshRequest)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(authResponseModel -> {
                    processResponse(authResponseModel, userName, encryptedPass);
                }, throwable ->
                {
                    LOGW(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
                }));
```

It's an authentication api. So when the api call fails, I get a response from the server like

```
{"messages":["Invalid username or password "]}
```

along with `400 Bad Request`

I get `400 Bad Request` in the `throwable` object as expected. But I want to receive the message thrown by the server. I am unable to figure out how to go about doing it.
Can someone help out.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983022/handle-errors-in-retrofit-2-rx) help

Comment: Nope. The throwable just gives 400 bad request.

Comment: did you check `((HttpException) e).response().errorBody()` ?

Comment: Even what you have suggested gives `Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=****/authenticate}`

Comment: `((HttpException) e).response()` returns the response object. There you have the real  body of the response, `response.body()` - usually for http 200 -   and the error body which should be filled in case of error. Check the content of both.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/DeserializeErrorBody.java) in Retrofit's codebase. It makes use of a `Converter` which maps the error body to a java object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(throwable instanceof HttpException) {
    //we have a HTTP exception (HTTP status code is not 200-300)
    Converter<ResponseBody, Error> errorConverter =
        retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]);
    //maybe check if ((HttpException) throwable).code() == 400 ??
    Error error = errorConverter.convert(((HttpException) throwable).response().errorBody());
}
```

Assuming you are using Gson:

```
public class Error {
    public List<String> messages;
}
```

the content of `messages` should be a list of error messages. In your example
`messages.get(0)` would be: Invalid username or password

Comment: retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]); Can you explain about this 'retrofit' object?

Comment: It is the Retrofit instance (from Retrofit 2)