# How to handle different kinds of errors in Retrofit Rx onError without ugly instanceof

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, onerror

I would like to know your ways to handle different kinds of errors (like http exceptions, no internet connection exceptions etc) in retrofit Rx onError without using `instanceof` like it's proposed here: [How to handle network errors in Retrofit 2 with RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987037/how-to-handle-network-errors-in-retrofit-2-with-rxjava) or here: [Handle errors in Retrofit 2 RX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983022/handle-errors-in-retrofit-2-rx)

In kotlin I will simply make some extension functions for each kind of throwable  to do whatever I want.

But I am forced to use Java in the project. Any nice suggestions?

is the approach to build some kind of error handler like this:

```
public interface ErrorHandler {
    void handleError(Exception e);
    void handleError(HttpException e);
    void handleError(NullPointerException npe);

}
```

good? I know it is not because every time i need to handle another specific error I am forced to change interface, so it is violation of Open Close Principle. But I can't figure out any solution .

cheers
Wojtek

Comment: this always will fall in the `handleError(Exception e)` implementation

Comment: hmmm, i wrote test for it and it didn't fail ... but it is irrelevant :P

Comment: I also wrote a test in Java 1.8 (u60) and it falls always in Exception method

Comment: maybe in java 8 On android works java 6.5 :P

Comment: This doesn't mean Android will stay forever on java 6.5. Most reasonable thing IMO here seems to have a Manager that register handlers for different type of exceptions - in other words - your interface should have only one `handleError` method which accepts `<E extends java.lang.Exception>`

Comment: imo, you probably didn't read question at all. The problem is how to avoid checking what kind of error is comming on every single time. In what you propose I will have to manualy check by instanceOf what kind of error I'm dealing with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115815/discussion-between-wojciech-maciejewski-and-mihail).

Comment: well, I don't have the time for chat. Just want to clarify something - you want to have one `try-catch` block where you just `catch(Exception e)`, then you expect the correct implementation to be called. Because this is what I just tested

Comment: No, I don't want to have simple try-catch block.  That is Rx chain where I just retrieve throwable in onError of my subscriber. If you spent 10 seconds and check any of links that i provided in my post you won't be confused. Please read post before comment next time

Comment: and if you spent 2 seconds to check that `Exception` is subclass of `Throwable`. I'm just wondering what kind of test you have wrote and it has passed

Comment: and so what that Throwable is parent class of Exception? what has it to the question? stopping answering you comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler determines which method to call, rather than the VM. So the class you've described won't solve the problem unless you check instanceof first and cast the paramter to the correct type. Otherwise you're going to get handleError(Exception e) every time.

But I wanted to create an answer not for that reason, but to argue that having only one error handler is actually preferable in many cases, not a liability. Oftentimes in java we end up in awful situations like this:

```
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No such algorithm: RSA?", e);
    }
    catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No such provider: " + ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ID, e);
    }
    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Bug setting up encryption key for user credentials: ", e);
    }
    catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Bug setting up encryption key for user credentials: ", e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Exception setting up keystore for user creds. They won't be stored.", e);
    }
    catch (CertificateException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Exception setting up keystore for user creds. They won't be stored.", e);
    }
```

Having only one error handler gives us the ability to lump many types of exceptions together. You can see in this code, there are exceptions that should never be thrown, exceptions that can really only be the result of a bug in the code, and legitimate exceptional states that we need to handle. I find this messy, and would prefer to say:

```
if (e instanceof NoSuchAlgorithmException || e instanceof NoSuchProviderException)  { 
    Log.wtf(TAG, "What the heck is this?", e);
    throw new IllegalStateException("This is some kind of weird bug", e);
}
else if (e instanceof IOException || e instanceof CertificateException) {
    // This can happen sometimes, track event in analytics and perhaps 
    // try some alternative means of credential storage.
} 
else {
    // At least here the app won't crash if some unexpected exception occurs,
    // since we're trapping everything.
}
```

I don't think it's such a bad thing to be able to lump unexpected failures together and handle them in a more user friendly way than crashing the app. Even if it's just a bug, better to track it in your analytics framework behind the scenes than bomb the user out of the app. So many crashes in Android apps are actually completely recoverable, but we don't go around catching Throwable in every try/catch statement because it's a lot of extra code.

Answer (score 1):

The proper OOP way to avoid chained `if`s or `catch`es is *polymorphism*. You can define several custom exception classes exposing common interface that is enough for a single handler to process.

Suppose you need to divide errors in two groups: recoverable and not recoverable. Then your base exception class (or interface) shall have abstract method `isRecoverable()` that you override in each subclass. Then there will be only one `if` in your handler: `if (e.isRecoverable()) { ... } else { ... }`.

The downside is that you have to wrap all standard exceptions into your custom ones at places where they are thrown (you have to catch them).

The right choice will greatly depend on your task, though.